# Sending laravel login email

Tags: laravel

I try to send email to users every time they login to their account in case if someone else is using their account so they can be notified,

so basically I want send this kind of information to logged user email:

```
account: user email (which this email sends to)
time: timestamp of loggin
ip address: ip of logged user
browser: information of logged user browser
```

PS:

In matter of fact currently I am storing all these information to my database for analytics purpose so I do have user last login time stamp, ip address, browser info but they are in separate tables, for example user last login time and ip are storing to `users` table while `browser info + user_id` are stored in another table named `user_trackers` so I need the way to gather all these info and send them by email.

## Question

How can I collect these info from 2 tables and send them to logged user email address?

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is in getting database? I suggest making a foreign key and take them [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) . After that, you can load and separately call in `App/Mail::build()`

Comment: My actual problem is sending email when user login, i cannot get user by using `$user` in login controller.

Comment: If you want to mail to logging on user, you can use `Auth::user()` to get infomation of current user. After that, getting other info by querying from DB, I think, not a big problem .